# How to align a node in the SceneKit scene editor

Tags: ios, keyboard-shortcuts, scenekit, scene

I am new to SceneKit, and I am trying to move nodes around the scene. How do I align a node to the node adjacent to it by making it 'snap into place'?

This is what it currently looks like when moving a node, it does not show ANY guide:

[image]

I do not want to manually change the values, as sometimes it shows `multiple`, as well as this being inconvenient and slow:

[image]

I can see there is an ability to make the node align (I assume using the keyboard or in some settings?) as seen on the [WWDC 2015 Enhancements to SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/606/) at `6m 20s`.

Notice - it 'snaps' into place next to the other wooden box:

[image]

How am I able to achieve this? What other keyboard shortcuts/settings do I need to know? (I only know about the `⌥ (option)` key which duplicates nodes)

Did Apple use some 3rd-party app?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Comment: Currently, Scenekit is for a programmer. Not for an artist job. Just find a right tool.

Comment: @E.Coms In the WWDC presentation they managed to snap the image in place in the editor. I know you can obviously add all the nodes programmatically, but I do not want to do that. Also, what do you mean by _find the right tool_?

Comment: There are many softwares can quickly do this and better at doing this.

Comment: @E.Coms I thought aligning a block in a scene would be much simpler, rather than downloading a 3rd-party software. So how did Apple do it then? Did they use something else?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapping is enabled by holding the command key (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) while dragging the object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this so many times previously, but it is important to note that you **MUST** hold `⌘` **BEFORE** you start moving. :)

Comment: Otherwise, it seems to lock into place, but where it shouldn't (it just locks from where you started to hold the key)

Comment: Also, sorry to bug you. Your profile shows that you know quite a lot about SceneKit. I am just wondering why [here in this video](https://streamable.com/aym1o) my blocks stay floating in the air after they are `removeFromParentNode()`. Thanks!